# Determening the preferred language for the user

Tags: java, servlets

I have a site that should be available to the user in both English and Swedish. My question is: How do I decide what language (and in turn, what numberformats etc) to display to the user.

The interface `javax.servlet.ServletRequest` defines the method `getLocale()` and says that it will return the locale based on the `Accept-language` header in the HTTP request. But this means that if a person with a German browser visits my site, the `Locale`object will be the German one. And since my site does not support German the locale in the request will not match any of my language files.

Is there a way to configure this or do I need to override the functionality of the `getLocale()` method to do this?

Is `getLocale()` the correct method to use for determening what language to displey to the user, or is the method supposed to be used for other purposes?

And to be clear, what I want is: If the locale supplied by the browser is supported by my site then use that one. Otherwise, use the default one for my site (english).

Comment: "And to be clear, what I want is: If the locale supplied by the browser is supported by my site then use that one. Otherwise, use the default one for my site (english)". Try expressing that in code, "locale supplied" as getLocale(). You might need some sort of collection of supported Locales defined somewhere ...

Comment: Yes that is right, I might need a collection. But is do I need to extend getLocale and is that method the right one to use for my porpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getLocale()` method is the right one, but there is no need to extend it. Java's normal [internationalization support](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/locale/) already gives you the behaviour you want, in a much easier and cleaner way.

For example, assume you provide the following language files:

- MyStrings.properties
- MyStrings_sv_SE.properties

The first file has your English text, and the second has your Swedish text. If the locale is Sweden, the Swedish language file will be used; otherwise the file with no language extension will be used.

To retrieve your text, you would do something like:

```
ResourceBundle strings = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyStrings");
String hello = strings.getString("HELLO_USER");
```